# How to inspect kotlin deprecated API usage

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to inspect deprecated API usage of kotlin.

I can inspect it of Java by checking Java > Code maturity > Deprecated API usage.

But, in kotlin section there is not the setting.(look following screenshot.)

Any idea?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you find any solution please update me.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated declarations in Kotlin are reported by the compiler, so there is no separate IDE inspection to detect those. You can run the "Annotator" inspection to see all compiler warnings including deprecations.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I tried with checking [General -> Annotator] , But It does not work as I expected. This message is shown [No suspicious code found.]. 

I used Android framework deprecated code (e.g. Activity.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) in kotlin file. 
@yole